# A website similar to puzzling but for the sciences

Tags: discussion

I went through an old [question today about biology SE vs biologists](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/biology-se-and-professional-biologists) discussion. This got me wondering. The principle problem we have in the sciences is that we are segmented into our respective niches. Therefore, it becomes incredibly difficult to ask questions here. Furthermore, many questions that a professional/academic scientist may have can be highly opinionated based on the hypothesis being favoured by the OP.

Why don't we create a proposal for a Science.SE or SciCollab.SE? Primarily, a website for all the primary science fields (Math, Physics, Chemisty and Biology, Stats)

This would be modelled off of Puzzling.SE. I am making a few assumptions here.

- A professional will only ask a question in his/her field after they are unable to come up with a suitable answer based on evidence from literature.
- Such a question may be answered in a different way. Such as by modelling.
- Finally, you can come to Science.SE and ask the question, where physicists, chemists, mathematicians can chip in their views about what it is you are trying to ask.
- The pro part is, you can find potential collaborators for the things that you are doing, on the way significantly improving your work and theirs.

I know there are a lot of loop holes here, so please tell me **why not**?

Why not do something similar loosely based off of Puzzling.SE?

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is **why not**...

I'm imagining a "biological" type of question that would be answered on that site, probably related to health, human consciousness, or loosely evolution, and the type of suggestive answer it's going to get from the people from those other groups who have no idea what plausible techniques are or what current thinking is in the field. It sounds like a recipe for bad questions and worse answers.

I'm also thinking of this: https://xkcd.com/793/

Also, this sounds exactly how it works now. When I have a stats question, I go ask it over at Stats.SE. If a chemist has a question about biology they can't answer, they come here to Bio.SE.

For these reasons, I'm out.